# Python Script not finding file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io

This basic python3 script cannot find the file "o.jpeg":

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("o.jpeg")
pixels = list(im.getdata())
```

I have verified that this image exists in the same directory as the `.py` file. Compilation is done in terminal. The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaron/Documents/NeoPixelControl/mediascript.py", line 9, in <module>
    im = Image.open("o.jpeg")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2770, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'o.jpeg'
```

Directory Listing:

```
$ ls
mediascript.py  o.jpeg
```

Comment: Are you running the python script from the same directory as the JPEG file? You could also try using an absolute path instead.

Comment: Have you tried ".jpg" instead?

Comment: I've tried the absolute path, no luck. Same directory. .jpg doesn't work either.

Comment: It could also be caused by permission issues.

Comment: sudo isn't working for me either.

Comment: @AaronMann can you do `ls -la o.jpeg` or another equivalent of your OS. i want to see the filename and its permissions

Comment: in addition to @anekix comment, please show the output of `ls` in the directory that contains your python script.

Comment: In addition to the above, please explain the way that you are running the script (terminal, ide, etc) and any relevant details (directory the shell is in, name & verison of the IDE, etc).

Comment: @Gideon Kimutai$ ls
mediascript.py  o.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

Try this once @Aaron :

```
im = Image.open(r"/home/aaron/Documents/NeoPixelControl/o.jpg")
```

Also for confusion with jpg and jpeg, try listing all the files present in the directory through python. This might help you debug.

```
import os
for file in os.listdir(r"/home/aaron/Documents/NeoPixelControl"):
    print(file)
```

Comment: cannot find that directory either. This problem is becoming bigger than just the library...

Comment: I suspect it to be permission error @Aaron. Try debugging it step by step starting with  permissions and directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PyCharm, maybe it's because PyCharm configuration.

Try run the script directly in the terminal.